# How can I specify a specific custom ordering with a SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've seen all the other answers on this but I haven't seen my specific problem addressed. Basically, I have a table with a bunch of duplicated values, and I need to select exactly one column (to concatenate into a list, ultimately, for output purposes), but with a specific item in that list FIRST. The problem I have is that I can specify the order, or I can specify distinct, but not both. And I CANNOT INCLUDE the order column in the SELECT because that output is going to be used directly, and having two columns in the output breaks everything. This seems like it should be possible, but I can't figure out how.

Here's a contrived example:

```
DECLARE @List TABLE ([Name] nvarchar(10));
INSERT INTO @List ([Name])
VALUES (N'A'), (N'A'), (N'B'), (N'B'), (N'B'), (N'C'), (N'D'), (N'D'), (N'J'), (N'X'), (N'X'), (N'Y');

-- Has both duplicates, and not in the right order
SELECT * FROM @List;
-- No duplicates, but not in the right order
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @List;
-- In the right order, but has duplicates
SELECT * FROM @List ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Name] = 'X' THEN '1' WHEN [Name] = 'Y' THEN '2' ELSE [Name] END;
```

What I want is a simple output like this:

```
X
Y
A
B
C
D
J
```

I've tried various approaches, with CTEs, and intermediate steps, but I really just want ONE select, that I can throw into a STUFF, so I get the string "X, Y, A, B, C, D, J", and I can't find any way to preserve the REQUIRED order while doing that. This HAS to be possible, so I'm clearly missing something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a group by instead of distinct.

```
SELECT [Name] 
FROM @List 
group by [Name]
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Name] = 'X' THEN '1' WHEN [Name] = 'Y' THEN '2' ELSE [Name] END ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have enough points to post a comment, so try to figure it out in an "answer".
You've mentioned that you should not include ordering column in the result set, so I assume that column defined in the table.
If so, then you can use a window functions for that purpose. Assume that column has a name `Ordering_Column`, then you may issue this:

```
select Name 
  from (
    select Name
         , row_number() over (partition by Name order by Ordering_Column) as Position
      from SomeTable
     order by Ordering_Column
  ) where Position = 1
```

This would return firstmost `Name` values from `SomeTable` sorted by `Ordering_Column`.